# javafx communicate with serial port with javax.comm

Tags: javafx-2, java-8, win32com, javax.comm, netbeans-8

In JDK 8 u 5 I have sample project that uses comm.jar and win32com.dll to communicate with a serial port.

I setup javax.comm correctly and put the related files in the JDK and JRE and was able to run sample code with out error.

I then created a JavaFx project with netbeans and used the sample source code, and also generate Key and set netBeans to sign my code. I also imported the cert to my system and this file to the java exception list.

When I run this with JavaFx it works correctly and communicates with the serial port.
but when run it on a browser I get a `javax.comm.NoSuchPortException`. If I click on the jnlp file and run it on web start the same things happens.

What is wrong? I'm sure javax.comm is correctly setup on my computer, the jar file is self signed, and the generated cert file is imported. Why does it work on desktop mode but do not work on browser and web start?